# Where a console application properties (like font, location, etc.) are remembered?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, console, file-shortcut

I start a console, by typing `start cmd`, or a PowerShell 7 console by typing `start pwsh`
Then I use left upper menu -> Properties to set font size, layout, etc.
Next time the particular console application starts with the remembered settings.

I understand, that in case in regular shortcuts, or pinned items those settings are stored in the .lnk file. However in the case I describing there is not shortcut, to be more precise I suppose there is somewhere but where?

Answer (score 1):

The information is stored in Windows registry under the `HKCU\Console`.

The key `HKCU\Console` contains defaults for new console and subkeys - properties of distinct applications.
The name of the subkey depends on how do you start the console, if could be either full path of executable, or the title of the console, if you run it as `start "ConEmu" cmd.exe /c something`.

Example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
"FaceName"="Consolas"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\ConEmu]
"NumberOfHistoryBuffers"=dword:00000020
"FaceName"="Lucida Console"
"FontSize"=dword:00050000
```